# How to call a POST method using gluon RESTClient

Tags: java, javafx, gluon

Below is the sample code . i want to call a rest api using gluon.

```
RestClient restClient = RestClient.create()
        .host("https://abc.api.in")
        .path("v1/signup")
        .formParam("name",name)
        .formParam("email",email)
        .formParam("password",password)
        .formParam("repeatPassword",repeatPassword)
        .formParam("refID",refID)
        .method("POST").contentType("text/plain");
GluonObservableObject<SignUpDAO> sample = DataProvider.retrieveObject(restClient.createObjectDataReader(SignUpDAO.class));
```

But it gives warning like and it is not showing any further progress.I am using Task to call rest client from my controller.

```
INFO: Created Rest Connection:
    Method: POST
    Request URL: urlname
    Form Params: {password=[test123], repeatPassword=[test123], name=[pqr], refID=[dsfdfkdlfk], email=[test@gmail.com]}
    ContentType: text/plain
    Consumer Credentials: null / null
Aug 19, 2016 12:17:20 PM com.gluonhq.connect.converter.JsonConverter readFromJson
INFO: Property password not defined on json object for class class com.gluonapplication.com.coinsecureapp.controller.SignUpDAO.
Aug 19, 2016 12:17:20 PM com.gluonhq.connect.converter.JsonConverter readFromJson
INFO: Property repeatPassword not defined on json object for class class com.gluonapplication.com.coinsecureapp.controller.SignUpDAO.
Aug 19, 2016 12:17:20 PM com.gluonhq.connect.converter.JsonConverter readFromJson
INFO: Property name not defined on json object for class class com.gluonapplication.com.coinsecureapp.controller.SignUpDAO.
Aug 19, 2016 12:17:20 PM com.gluonhq.connect.converter.JsonConverter readFromJson
INFO: Property refID not defined on json object for class class com.gluonapplication.com.coinsecureapp.controller.SignUpDAO.
Aug 19, 2016 12:17:20 PM com.gluonhq.connect.converter.JsonConverter readFromJson
INFO: Property email not defined on json object for class class com.gluonapplication.com.coinsecureapp.controller.SignUpDAO.
```

Comment: I'm using `RestClient`to access my Firebase DataBase. Here the `POST` request doesn't store the actual object but returns an answer containing the identifier for that object, leaving the object fields empty, hence the `Property {field} not defined` messages. To store the object I have to send a `PUT` request with the identifier as the path suffix.

Comment: I am using HTTP client .its working as charm . anyway thank you for you reply :)